# moving locally stored documented documents to azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform, azure-blob-storage

I want to spike whether azure and the cloud is a good fit for us.

We have a website where users upload documents to our currently hosted website.

Every document has an equivalent record in a database.

I am using terraform to create the azure infrastructure.

What is my best way of migrating the documents from the local file path on the server to azure?

Should I be using file storage or blob storage.  I am confused about the difference.

Is there anything in terraform that can help with this?

Comment: Once the files are in Azure, how would they be used? For example, would these files be used in any application like images etc.? Please edit your question and include the usage pattern and provide other details.

Comment: @GauravMantri mainly word documents that are updated and downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would recommend storing them in [`Blob Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction). This service is suited for storing and serving unstructured data like files and images. There are many other features like redundancy, archiving etc. that you may find useful in your scenario.

File Storage is more suitable in Lift-and-Shift kind of scenarios where you're moving an on-prem application to the cloud and the application writes data to either local or network attached disk.

You may also find this article useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks

**UPDATE**

Regarding uploading files from local computer to Azure Storage, there are actually many options available:

- Use a Storage Explorer like Microsoft's Storage Explorer.
- Use `AzCopy` command-line tool.
- Use `Azure PowerShell` Cmdlets.
- Use `Azure CLI`.
- Write your own code using any available Storage Client libraries or directly consuming REST API.

Comment: hi, the question was mainly about how to get an existing directory structure to azure

Comment: `Should I be using file storage or blob storage. I am confused about the difference.` - I thought you wanted to know about that :).

Comment: Is your question about how to upload the files in Storage?

Comment: apologies if this was misleading, i think azcopy is the right answer

Comment: No worries :). Yep, azcopy is definitely an option. Updated my answer to include some other options as well.